# Sqlalchemy: How to update a column every 24 hours?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on A REST API with python flask and I have implemented the following schema via sql-alchemy.

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime
from app.utilities.commons import *

class User(db.model):
    id = id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=get_unique_id())
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=False)
    organism = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False, unique=False)
    allowed_access_per_day = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True, default=None)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

What I want to do is to reset the attribute `allowed_access_per_day` (update it to 0) everyday 00h00 am. 
What I am doing as a temporary solution is to make a python thread that update the table every 24h which is not a good idea as it does not keep the same behaviour to all application connecting to the database.
I want to make this behaviour specific to the database (just like triggers and timers in SQL).
How to make it in sql-alchemy?

Answer (score 2):

you could insert an additional column, in which you write for which date `allowed_access_per_day` was set.
In the query you check then, if it is from the previous day.

Comment: I don't want to handle the behaviour from python code or sql query. I want to make a default behaviour in database itself. (just like triggers and timers in sql)

Answer (score 1):

In core sqlalchemy I haven't found something like jobs/scheduling. There are some additonal packages as addon to sqlalchemy. 
It seems that you have to write the scheduling of

```
users.update().values(allowed_access_per_day =0)
```

yourself.